# Send adaptive card in email through AWS email service (SES)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses, adaptive-cards

I have a nodejs application by which I am trying to figure out if we can send adaptive cards in email using a third party layer like Amazon SES. As per microsoft documentation the adaptive card data needs to be in header under script tags.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/send-via-email

I am receiving the emails but the card is not visible in the email, the text apart of adaptive card is visible. But when I go to View source of the email I do see the adaptive card content in the raw email data.
Email data -

```
<script = type=3D"application/adaptivecard+json"> { "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json", "type": "AdaptiveCard", "version": "1.0", "originator": "", "body": [ { "size": "large", "text": "Hello Actionable message", "wrap": true, "type": "TextBlock" } ], "actions": [ { "type": "Action.InvokeAddInCommand", "title": "Open Actionable Messages Debugger", "addInId": "3d1408f6-afb3-4baf-aacd-55cd867bb0fa", "desktopCommandId": "amDebuggerOpenPaneButton" } ] } </script>If the card doesn't appear, install Actionable Me= ssages Debugger Outlook add-in to debug the issue.
```

I tried sending adaptive card using https://amdesigner.azurewebsites.net/ which works as expected.
Not sure if using a third party layer for sending adaptive card requires any additional setting.

Comment: I hadn't heard of these before but given that you debug them in Outlook this looks like a Microsoft proprietary thing.  Something has to parse those headers and add them to the body and SES won't do that.

Comment: But as per Microsoft if the card is parsed as html content in header under the script tags there's no more changes required by caller.